Creating pure monochromes by separating constituent waves
Since we cannot create a pure monochromatic wave, consider a white light wave and let it pass through a prism. Are the colored waves produced by this non-monochromatic as well? If yes, then can't we pass them through other separating filters, until we reach a pure monochrome?

Doing this would be like trying to create a mathematical line by cutting a piece of paper into thinner and thinner strips. It becomes impractical long before you approach the ideal result you are looking for.

A filter that removes all frequency components outside a finite bandwidth, (compact support),  must have an infinite long impulse response, see the Paley-Wiener theorem. As a consequence, no signal can have compact support in both the time and frequency domains. Since no real life signal can extend in time or space to infinity in either direction, it can neither possess a finite spectral extent. This is true for any linear system, such as a prism, an RLC filter, a piano, etc.

No filter will produce an ABSOLUTE 'pure monochrome'; there are line width limitations in colored-glass items, diffraction gratings have some non ideal features that are related to the 'blaze' character, and prism color separation is
only pure if there's a zero-width slit defining the light path
(and zero-width slits don't pass much light...).
Some very-nearly-monochromatic sources do exist (like, an FM broadcast
station transmitting a silent passage), but absolutely pure  wavelength
character is intrinsically related to the duration of the wave: if it
wasn't ALWAYS generating the electromagnetic disturbance, the limited
time duration causes a frequency bandwidth.
Gamma ray sources that exhibit the Mossbauer effect are extremely
pure, but there's a few parts in $ 10^{13} $ of
frequency deviation to be seen, even in that case.  Mossbauer experiment
